# successively url redirection to page A or page B

Tags: javascript

I want to test the success of different styles of a landing page. I found a code which generates a redirection randomly to page A or page B. But I want to have it successively like on first pageload the user gets page A on second pageload page B and so on.

Here is the code for the random redirection. What do I need to change to get it successively?

```js
var redirect, pageOptions = ['a.html', 'b.html'];
if (Math.random() < .5){
    redirect = pageOptions[0];
} else {
    redirect = pageOptions[1];
}
window.location.assign(redirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use to localStorage which is builtin in major of the browser.
Here is the sample code:

```js
var redirect, pageOptions = ['a.html', 'b.html'];

var getCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("redirectCount"));

if(getCount == null){
   getCount = 0;
}
else{
   getCount = (getCount+1)%2 ;
}

localStorage.setItem("redirectCount", getCount);
redirect = pageOptions[getCount];

window.location.assign(redirect);
```

Comment: Hi Sushan Sapaliga, thank you for your answer. Just tried it but that codes ads to the url /undefined which is no valid page. it needs to lead to a.html or b.html. Do you know what I made wrong? For information. The test audience which gets the url are all in a different place and have different computers. So I guess the localStorage can´t do the trick?

Comment: The question you have posted says that when the user reloads the page, he must be taken to one of the URLs in the array successively. I guess you need to elaborate on the question you have posted.

Comment: You can keep a database, which remembers the state of the user throughout the place and across different computers.